# Gradle error : "Failed to apply plugin [id ‘myappid’] "

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My question is regarding gradle & pls understand that I am new to it. My android app is supposed to build command-line using gradle on an osx machine using a script.

After resolving many issues with proxy & connectivity, I am finally getting an **error as below** when I run my script which is trying to build my android app with gradle:

```
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android-build'.
    > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.mycompany.myappid']
    > Plugin with id 'com.mycompany.myappid' not found.
```

**How can I fix this issue ?**

My build.gradle looks like below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven  {
            url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.mycompany.myappid'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

        def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + 1

        versionProps['VERSION_CODE']=code.toString()
        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

        defaultConfig {
            versionCode code
            versionName "1.1"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 18
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for the `com.mycompany.myappid` plugin? You need to add it to the buildscript dependencies.

Comment: build.gradle is located inside the app source that is required to be built. How do I add it as a dependency. could you provide a sample syntax pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
apply plugin: 'com.mycompany.myappid'
```

You are applying a plugin with this name that doens't exist (may it is your package name).

You should apply this plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get this error, it is always best to re-run with "--stacktrace" (shortcut: "-s"). It will give a more detailed stacktrace that usually pinpoints the line that doesn't work out in the script.

Comment: I enabled stacktrace, it complains about the line where the android block starts -- `android {` . Is this because of some environment variable ? I have set `JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_SDK, GRADLE_HOME` everything in the path. I am sure my project code does not have issues.it was building with ant. Just that it fails to build with gradle. Can you pls suggest what could be missing here ?